# Please, explain what does the following line of "with.. do" represent

Tags: delphi

In the code: pbOut is a TPaintBox.

```
 with pbOut.Canvas, Font do 
 begin
 ....
 end;
```

The question is, i want to understand what does the comma in with.. do structure do? Is it the same as writing with pbOut.Canvas.Font do or not?

Comment: The answer would be yes, it is `pbOut.Canvas.Font`. Avoid `with` like the plague, you will thank me later...

Comment: It brings `pbOut.Canvas.Font` into the `with` block access. And chaos. It brings chaos.

Comment: Did you consider reading the documentation?

Comment: I have. But it confused me a little bit.

Comment: It says: When multiple objects or records appear after with, the entire statement is treated like a series of nested with statements. Thus:

`with obj1, obj2, ..., objn do statement`
is equivalent to:

  `with obj1 do
   with obj2 do
     ...
     with objn do
       // statement` That couldn't be much clearer. You need to read documentation carefully, all the way to the end.

Comment: It was said in the documentation: with obj1 do
   with obj2 do
     ...
     with objn do
         each variable reference or method name in statement is interpreted, if possible, as a member of objn; otherwise it is interpreted, if possible, as a member of objn1; and so forth. So in my example    with pbOut.Canvas, Pen, Font do
    begin
      Style:= psDot;
      MoveTo(30, 30);
      LineTo(150 , 100);

    end;
 the compiler brings up an error  "Style:= psDot"  Why is it erroneous? Why isn't Style:= psDot intepreted as a member of Pen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because Style is also a member of `Font` and right here you have the salutary lesson of `with`. You now know never to use it ever again ever.

Comment: @ArthurHmayakyan I explained the issue of clashing identifier names in my answer.

Comment: I wonder when Embarcadero's going to finally get rid of this pesky "feature".

Comment: *what does the comma in with.. do structure do?* That's easy. It makes already bad code even worse. `with` is a legacy curse, and writing code using it makes that code very poor. Adding the comma with yet another variable to the mix changes that *very poor* code into absolute crap code.

Comment: So should i always use methods with their qualifiers?

Comment: @whosrdaddy it will make the members of pbOut.Canvas *and* (pbOut.Canvas.Font *or* self.Font) available without explicitly prefixem them with the respective instances. Regarding to avoid with I am with ;-) you. Don't use it, you will always live to regret it. How long have we been petitioning Borland, Codegear and Embarcadero to at least add a compiler hint / warning for its usage?

Comment: I noticed that you have not accepted either of the answers to your question. Maybe you don't know what it means, therefore, please visit [**someone-answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) page in the help.

Comment: @JerryDodge - Marco Cantu already answered that: never

Comment: @ArthurHmayakyan - Do you see what you started here? Do you? :)

Answer (score 10):

The comma is simply a separator for a list of things to 'scope to' using **with**.

As to your question, *strictly speaking*: it depends...

You might make the assumption that `pbOut.Canvas` always has a `Font` property (because you know `TCanvas` has a `Font` property). But nothing forces a `Canvas` variable to be of the `TCanvas` type, so you actually have to consider 2 possibilities.

*In your case the first possibility explained below most likely applies, but it's important to be aware of the other.*

As to your specific question:

> Is it the same as writing `with pbOut.Canvas.Font do` or not?

It's almost the same, but not quite. That doesn't expose `pbOut.Canvas`, which the original code *does*.

---

### Possibility 1

If `Font` is a member of `pbOut.Canvas`, then the statement is equivalent to:

```
with pbOut.Canvas do
begin
  with pbOut.Canvas.Font do 
  begin
    { See notes underneath }
  end;
end;
```

Here you are able to reference members of either `pbOut.Canvas` or `pbOut.Canvas.Font` directly; without fully qualifying the reference.

Any members in both `pbOut.Canvas` and `pbOut.Canvas.Font` that have have the same identifier would clash. The compiler will favour the inner with item. This means you would still have to fully qualify the `pbOut.Canvas` member to access it.

---

### Possibility 2

On the other hand, if `Font` is ***not*** an accessible member of `pbOut.Canvas`, then the statement is equivalent to:

```
with pbOut.Canvas do
begin
  with Font do 
  begin
    { See notes underneath }
  end;
end;
```

Similar to the previous construct, you can access members of either `pbOut.Canvas` or `Font` directly; without fully qualifying the reference.

---

I must point out that the **with** statement is not really a useful construct.

- It leads to confusing, difficult to read code because you always have to consider *what* an unqualified identifier *really* refers to.
- There also a risk that adding/removing/renaming members in an existing object or record type might unexpectedly break existing code. Any code using **with** on instance of the modified type might unexpectedly scope differently.
- The **with** list form in your question is even worse than single **with** because of the added trickery covered in my answer.

The **with** statement saves a small amount of code to more explicitly qualify certain identifiers; i.e. minimal "typing" savings, but at a great cost. So it is advised to not use **with**.

Comment: By definition the statement is always equivalent to possibility 2. That's explicitly stated in the documentation. So then the question becomes whether or not the inner object is part of the outer object's scope, or not.

Comment: @David Yeah, that's a more accurate way of describing it. It was trying to illustrate the effect.

Comment: Obviously I am too late here to answer, and your answer is as usual very good, but I do feel that the key extracts from the documentation should be included in an answer. Specifically the text I quoted in a comment to the Q.

Comment: In the times of Wirth, `with` was a useful construct. It was not multi-level, and there were not so many scope issues as you see now. It allowed the compiler to generate optimized code. These days, `with`, especially multi-level `with` like here, has to deal with too many scopes in which an identifier can live. No problem for the compiler, but it can be a big problem for us humans.

Comment: @rudy The compiler never needed any help from `with`. That's a myth.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, not sure what compiler you mean. The TP compiler added all `with` references into a stack list, and if the same reference were used multiple times, it could lead to an optimization. (Taken from what I can recollect from memory). I cursed the use of `with` even 25 years ago, but still have to live with remnants in code used today.

Comment: @LURD That's as maybe but Rudy claimed that with allowed the compiler to make an optimisation. In other words, without with the optimisation couldn't be made. That's clearly false.

Answer (score 5):

Look into [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#With_Statements):

> A with statement is a shorthand for referencing the fields of a record or the fields, properties, and methods of an object. The syntax of a with statement is:
>
> ```
> with obj do statement
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> with obj1, ..., objn do statement
> ```
>
> where obj is an expression yielding a reference to a record, object instance, class instance, interface or class type (metaclass) instance, and statement is any simple or structured statement. Within the statement, you can refer to fields, properties, and methods of obj using their identifiers alone, that is, without qualifiers.
>
> When multiple objects or records appear after with, the entire statement is treated like a series of nested with statements. Thus:
>
> ```
> with obj1, obj2, ..., objn do statement
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>  with obj1 do
>    with obj2 do
>      ...
>      with objn do
>        // statement
> ```
>
> In this case, each variable reference or method name in statement is interpreted, if possible, as a member of objn; otherwise it is interpreted, if possible, as a member of objn1; and so forth. The same rule applies to interpreting the objs themselves, so that, for instance, if objn is a member of both obj1 and obj2, it is interpreted as obj2.objn.
>
> Since a with statement requires a variable or a field to operate upon, using it with properties can be tricky at times. A with statement expects variables it operates on to be available by reference.

---

Generally using `with` is a recipe for disaster, since by the look of it, it is difficult to know if a statement refers to one of the `with` blocks (and which one) or an outer scope.

---

To answer the question,

> Is it the same as writing with pbOut.Canvas.Font do or not?

If you only want to access the `Font` properties it is the same, but not if you want to access other members of pbOut.Canvas.

For yours and others sake, do not use `with` statements at all.